# runOutsideAngular not working with more number of dom elements

Tags: angular5, zone.js

I have been working on angular 5 from the last few months now. And I wanted to implement draggable functionality. I have written my code in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-hvzjos

I am trying to use runOutsideAngular which almost worked when I had one child div with the draggable event inside the parent div with the draggable event as well. whereas when I am trying to add one more child div

with the draggable event, the runoutsideangular doesn't seem to be working it triggers multiple mouse move and mouse leave change detection's in zone.js which is making the page very very slow.

I am stuck in this problem probably from the last 2 days Can anyone help me, please.

I also figured out when the dom elements increase with draggable event zone.js starts appearing gain even after specifying runOutsideAngular